# Exchange 2010: Find Move Request Log after move request completes

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs-2003, windows-sbs-2011

EDIT: significantly changed my question here to streamline it a bit.  I've gone ahead and used 100 as my corrupted item count and ran it from the Exchange Shell.

So the trail of tears continues with my SBS 2003 to 2011 migration: all the mailboxes have moved mailbox store from `OLDSERVER` to `NEWSERVER`, with the Local Move Requests completing successfully, except for one.

What I'd like to do now is review the previous move request log files: when they were in progress, I could right-click Properties > Log > View Log File, but now that they're completed, that's not available.  Nor can I use:

`Get-MoveRequestStatistics <user> -includereport | fl MoveReport`

...as the move request has now completed and it errors out with "couldn't find a move request that corresponds...".

Basically what I'd like to do is present the list of baditems to the user so that they're aware of what items didn't come across and if anything important was lost, be able to check their current OST, an archive.pst, etc. to recover it if possible.

If this all needs to be wrapped up in a batch Exchange power shell command to pipe the output to log files on disk somewhere, I'm all ears, and would appreciate it for the next migration we do.

Comment: Why is the local move request failing? too many corrupt items?

Comment: Definitely saw some in the logs, but now that I've cancelled the move request, I'm not sure where the logs are to confirm that was the reason; bit blury-eyed last night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To literally answer your question, no, there is no way to change the mailbox from legacy user to user mailbox.

However, you can delete just the mailbox and create a new one. Make sure to copy all of the addresses from the old mailbox on to the new one. Also get the current Distinguished Name from the current mailbox and add it as an x500 address on the new mailbox.

But this is less than optimal. You should instead restart the mailbox migration and open a new question about why that move is failing.

To see the logs from a previous move, use this powershell command:

```
(Get-Mailbox **alias** | Get-MailboxStatistics -IncludeMoveHistory).MoveHistory
```

Comment: I've restarted it several times.  What I'd like to be able to do is find where the log persists _after_ the move fails.  right-click properties has nothing now that the move request has been cancelled, but is there a persisted log file somewhere so I can review and fix before starting again?

Comment: See my edit above.